# How to sequence your test cases using ExecutorService unit testing

Tags: java, junit

I am using ExecutorService to run parallel junit tests. Each test uses a random number generator to identify itself and run independent of the other tests. My scenario is like this

- Test 1 Add new users into the system
- Test 2 Search for users with certain characteristics in the system
- Test 2.1 Select one of the searched users, and send a request
- Test 3 Now use identity from Test 1, and check if there is a request pending. But this test cannot run until 1 and 2 have run. Also they need some data from test1.

I know I can use public static variables to save and restore the data from test1. Any ideas on doing this neatly. Dont want to create a bad impression 1st day at work.

Sample Code below

```
public class TestCases {
    static ExecutorService exe ;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        test1() ;
        test2() ;
        test3() ;
    }

   public static void test1() {
       exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() ;
       for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
           Test1 test1 = new Test1() ;
           exe.execute(test1) ;
        }
        exe.shutdown() ;
        while(!exe.isShutDown()) {
        }
    }
    //same for test2 and test3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to merge Test1 and Test2 as a subset of Test3. Infact all these together can be a Test4. This way you will be testing only 1 particular scenario. I suggest that you think in a way to create scenario based testing.